# Loop keeps going on forever

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, file-io, while-loop

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code. I'm trying to get the user name and password from the user and read a file that contains multiple user names and passwords. If the username and password are not on the same line, the user has 2 more attempts to get it right, otherwise, the program will exit. At the moment, the code is saying the username and password are wrong even when the user enters the right information, also, it is prompting the user more than 3 times. Could someone please help? I have the code below. I didn't post the headings because I think it might be a little confusing. Thank you!

```
//*****Prompts user to enter in user name and password
    System.out.println("Please enter in your user name: ");
    userName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter in your password: ");
    password = keyboard.nextLine();
    while (userName.equals("done"))
    {
      System.out.println("You entered done. Now exiting the test");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    while (userInfoScanner.hasNext())
        {
          String userInfoLine = userInfoScanner.nextLine();
          String [] userInfoArr = userInfoLine.split ("\t");
          // for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
          //{ 
          if(userInfoArr[0].equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && userInfoArr[1].equals(password))
          {
            System.out.println("Correct");
          }
          while (!userInfoArr[0].equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && !userInfoArr[1].equals(password))
          {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("Incorrect. Please enter in the correct user name: ");
              userName = keyboard.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Please enter in the correct password: ");
              password = keyboard.nextLine();
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: You have three nested loops. I am pretty sure that this is too much. Also, you prompt the user for username and password in the innermost loop. I would have expected this to be in the outermost loop.

Comment: No, I prompted the user outside the loop. I should have put that in the code. I'm sorry. I just edited the code. @Turing85

Comment: Still: if you enter the innermost `for`-loop, you will execute it exactly three times, unconditionally, without further checks. I am quite sure that this is not what you want. Try to re-arrange the program so that you prompt the user for username and password inside the outermost loop and the outermost loop only (a `do ... while(...) ` loop may be useful).

Comment: so I should put where I prompt the user the first time in a do-while loop?

Comment: Wait actually can you explain it again? In a different way? I'm a bit confused @Turing85

Comment: Contact me via [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com), I do not want to spam the comment section.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a reputation of 17, so I can't chat @Turing85

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158273/discussion-between-malia-and-turing85).

Answer (score 0):

You `while (userInfoScanner.hasNext())`  loop depends on user input, but user can write something always, so this while loop will be forever.

You can write more briefly.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter in your user name: ");
        String userName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter in your password: ");
        String password = keyboard.nextLine();

        while (userName.equals("done"))
        {
            System.out.println("You entered done. Now exiting the test");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Enter login and password");
        String userInfoLine = keyboard.nextLine();
        String [] userInfoArr = userInfoLine.split (" "); // i changed separation from \t to simple space

        if(userInfoArr[0].equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && userInfoArr[1].equals(password))
        {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }
        while (!userInfoArr[0].equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && !userInfoArr[1].equals(password))
        {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Please enter in the correct user name: ");
            userName = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter in the correct password: ");
            password = keyboard.nextLine();

        }
```

Comment: Im sorry, I dont really understand what youre trying to say?